# Cant mount Window's partition on bootable ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, live-usb, windows-10, disk

I am trying to recover some files from a Window's PC that is not booting up. So i am using my usb with Ubuntu to boot from there and recover the files.
When I try to mount the partition using the GUI Disks app it shows an error saying this:

> Error mounting filesystem
>
> Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/ubuntu/Acer: Unknown error when mounting /dev/sda3 (udisks-error-quark, 0)

It also shows a disk health alert saying: **Disk is likely to fail soon**

Is this disk completely dead or do I need to do something before mounting the NTFS disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying with many distros using Medicat (an usb tookit) and not being able to mount nor access the disk in any way, and after all the tests I ran on the disk failing and returning a 0% health status. I assume the disk has a mechanical issue. I will try unplugging it and reading it with another machine running windows but I'm 99% sure the disk is dead. And as that no longer concerns ubuntu I'll mark this answer as the solution.

PS: If you are also having trouble mounting a windows partition try to mount as read-only, and if the disk health status is good and you still can't it may be one of the reasons @Davmor2 mentioned in its answer: the windows partition might be hibernated or the disk could be encrypted

Comment: After trying to mount it on Windows10 it crashed the file explorer, and could not read the disk, it was definetly damaged

Answer (score 0):

Windows marks drives as dirty if they are not closed correctly this would prevent Ubuntu mounting them.  If that is the case boot windows let it start up and from the login screen select shutdown.

If the drive is encrypted by windows this too would prevent mounting.  There may be ways round that but you would need to look that up on Google.